# Ошибка 1067 при запуске сервиса MySQL

Tags: mysql, сервисы

Я добавила в службы MySQL с помощью *bat*-файла:

> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1.72\bin\mysqld"
>   --install-manual MySQL5_1_72  --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1.72\my.ini"

Получила сообщение, что установка произошла успешно. Но при запуске сервиса *MySQL5_1_72* появляется ошибка 1067:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём её причина и как избавиться от этой ошибки?

**UPD - логи MySQL:**

> 161208 15:03:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1.72\bin\mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin'
>   doesn't exist
>
> 161208 15:03:58 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin
>   table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
>
> 161208 15:03:58  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 300.0M
>
> 161208 15:03:58  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> InnoDB: The first specified data file E:\MySQL Datafiles_5_1_72\ibdata1 did not exist:
>
> InnoDB: a new database to be created!
>
> 161208 15:03:58  InnoDB: Setting file
>
> E:\MySQL Datafiles_5_1_72\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
>
> InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>
> 161208 15:03:58  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
>
> InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 60 MB
>
> InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>
> 161208 15:03:58  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
>
> InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 60 MB
>
> InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>
> InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
>
> InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
>
> InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
>
> InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
>
> 161208 15:03:59  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 0
>
> 161208 15:03:59 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Comment: Что написано в логе MySQL? Он лежит в папке %datadir% и имеет имя <имя_компьютера>.err

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, этот файл не создался. В my.ini прописано datadir="E:/MySQL_Base_5_1_72/", а папки такой на диске E нет...

Comment: Так не бывает. MySQL без этой папки работать не может. В этой папке должны лежать все базы данных. В том числе и системная база `mysql`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, или это (datadir из my.ini) не та папка %data_dir%?

Comment: Именно та. Вы все правильно поняли

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, или эту папку нужно создавать вручную, самому?

Comment: Нужно создать ее и перенести все файлы и папки из оригинальной datadir

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, я создала папку и запустила сервис ещё раз. После этого логи появились - добавила их в сообщение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> я создала папку

Этого мало

Как я говорил, в этой папке должны лежать все базы данных. В том числе и системная база `mysql`. Если Вы папку создали самостоятельно, то нужно перенести в нее все файлы и папки из оригинальной datadir, кроме файлов `ib_logfile*`. Это файлы журналов движка InnoDB. Их размер и количество зависит от настроек в my.ini. При их несоответствии, сервер отказывается стартовать. А вот при отсутствии этих файлов сервер сам создаст их в соответствии с настройками. Что Вы и наблюдали

> 161208 15:03:58 InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
>
> InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 60 MB
>
> InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>
> 161208 15:03:58 InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
>
> InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 60 MB

Comment: Да, спасибо, после переноса папки бд "mysql" проблема решилась

Answer (score 0):

Должно вам помочь:

Выполните следующие шаги:

1. Win + R и выполните команду `cmd`.
2. Переместитесь в папку с вашим сервером
   Пример - `“C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.0\bin”`.
3. Выполните команду “mysqld-nt.exe –console”. Если она выполнилась без ошибок, тогда необходимо проверить файл “my.ini”.
4. Выполните редактирование

`[mysqld]
port = 3306
basedir=”C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.0″
datadir=”c:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.0\Data”`

Путь указывайте свой.

Теперь всё должно работать.

Comment: у меня не было в папке bin файла "mysqld-nt.exe"... только "mysqld.exe"

Comment: ну и после выполнения команды `mysqld-nt.exe –console` в консоли следующее: `[Warning] option 'open_files_limit': unsigned value 3000 adjusted to 2048 || [ERROR] mysqld-nt.exe: unknown option '-c'`