# не удалось запустить службу mysql ошибка 1067

Tags: mysql

не удалось запустить службу mysql ошибка 1067

[image: вот такая ошыбка, кто знает в чем может быть проблема, помогите!]

Comment: Мало данных. Что в логе?

Comment: В файлах my.ini или my.cnf проверьте указан ли параметр basedir в секции [mysqld]. А также проверьте в переменных средах указан ли путь до */bin папки MySQL сервера.

Comment: #Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"

#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/

где найти "  переменных средах указан ли путь до */bin папки MySQL сервера "

Comment: http://files.dp.ua/file?source=19040413491132751235
Пароль 1111
там все логи

Comment: не дубль ли? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601092/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-1067-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql

Comment: у меня есть такая папка
 #Path to the database root datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/
но basedir совсем в другом каталоге
#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this. basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"

нужно чтобы они быль в одном?